# How to get my javascript countdown function to work with my database values

Tags: javascript, php, html

[I want the countdown to be displayed for each product and it's not just showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmfLf.png)

I'm trying to show a countdown for the dates in my database, but it's not working. I'm at a loss on what to do. I have the countdown timer function written but I'm having some problems passing the date from my database into the function. I have tried everything but it just doesn't display the countdown date.

```
<?php 
session_start();
include('../dbcon.php');
include("../header.php");
?>
<script>
function countdowntimer(id, time) 
{
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date(time).getTime();
    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {
    // Get today's date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
  }, 1000);
}
</script>
<div class="container">
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <table class="table">
            <?php 
                $item_query ="SELECT * FROM stock WHERE status= 'Active'";
                $item_query_run = mysqli_query($con,$item_query);
                $item_query_run_check = mysqli_num_rows($item_query_run);
                if ($item_query_run_check > 0){
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($item_query_run)) {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <?php  echo '<img src="data:image;base64,'.base64_encode($row['stock_image']).'" alt="Image" style="width: 100%; height: 280px;">'?> </td>
                            <td> <?php  echo $row['stock_name']?> <br>
                                 <?php  echo $row['stock_description']?> <br>
                                 <?php  echo $row['starting_bid']?><br>
                                 <?php  echo $row['reserve_price']?> <br>
                                 <?php  echo $row['auction_date_end']?> <br>
                                 <?php  echo $row['stock_id']?>
                        <script>
                            countdowntimer('<?php echo $row['stock_id']; ?>', '<?php echo date("M d, Y H:i:s",strtotime($row['auction_date_end'])); ?>');
                        </script>
                            </td>
                            <td> 
                                <button class="btn btn-info"><a href="view-seller-profile.php?sellereditid=<?php echo $edit_seller_id;?>">Place bid</a></button>
                                <a class='btn btn-danger' href="seller-delete.php?deletesellerid=<?php echo $delete_seller_id;?>">Watch</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
<?php 
include("../footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: In what specific way does this fail?  Use your browser's debugging tools.  What is the actual resulting PHP output in the page source?  Are there any errors on the browser's console?  Using the browser's script debugger, when you step through the code, what happens?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Where is the element with `demo` id?

Comment: You could try to do a static markup version first (without any database access), and then change the parts you need to dynamic variables. Monitor your markup in between to check which change breaks that whole thing

Comment: "it just doesn't display the countdown date" - why not inspect the generated markup to check **why** this happens? Does your browser's error console print anything useful?

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to just pass javascript a timestamp it already recognizes. You are passing a date that looks like this: `February 22, 2022 23:22:00`

Instead, just pass the number of milliseconds: `strtotime($row['auction_date_end']) * 1000`

```
countdowntimer('<?php echo $row['stock_id']; ?>', '<?php echo strtotime($row['auction_date_end']) * 1000; ?>');
```

Comment: I tried you answer and it still doesn't work. it's not outputting anything